# how to look for column heading in excels in single folder and return in summary sheet

Tags: vba, excel

the below code simply return what is in range ("Q33:AS33"), how can i modify it to look for key words(column heading) and return the text below the column heading (1 cell) to the summary sheet? many thanks

```
Sub MergeAllWorkbooks()
    Dim MyPath As String, FilesInPath As String
    Dim MyFiles() As String
    Dim SourceRcount As Long, FNum As Long
    Dim mybook As Workbook, BaseWks As Worksheet
    Dim sourceRange As Range, destrange As Range
    Dim rnum As Long, CalcMode As Long
    Dim FindString As String
    Dim FindCell As Range

    ' Change this to the path\folder location of your files.
    MyPath = "path name"

    ' Add a slash at the end of the path if needed.
    If Right(MyPath, 1) <> "\" Then
        MyPath = MyPath & "\"
    End If

    ' If there are no Excel files in the folder, exit.
    FilesInPath = Dir(MyPath & "*.xl*")
    If FilesInPath = "" Then
        MsgBox "No files found"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ' Fill the myFiles array with the list of Excel files
    ' in the search folder.
    FNum = 0
    Do While FilesInPath <> ""
        FNum = FNum + 1
        ReDim Preserve MyFiles(1 To FNum)
        MyFiles(FNum) = FilesInPath
        FilesInPath = Dir()
    Loop

    ' Set various application properties.
    With Application
        CalcMode = .Calculation
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    ' Add a new workbook with one sheet.
    Set BaseWks = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet).Worksheets(1)
    rnum = 1

    ' Loop through all files in the myFiles array.
    If FNum > 0 Then
        For FNum = LBound(MyFiles) To UBound(MyFiles)
            Set mybook = Nothing
            On Error Resume Next
            Set mybook = Workbooks.Open(MyPath & MyFiles(FNum))
            On Error GoTo 0

            If Not mybook Is Nothing Then
                On Error Resume Next

                ' Change this range to fit your own needs.
                With mybook.Worksheets("worksheet name")
                    Set sourceRange = .Range("Q33:AS33")
                End With

                If Err.Number > 0 Then
                    Err.Clear
                    Set sourceRange = Nothing
                Else
                    ' If source range uses all columns then
                    ' skip this file.
                    If sourceRange.Columns.Count >= BaseWks.Columns.Count Then
                        Set sourceRange = Nothing
                    End If
                End If
                On Error GoTo 0

                If Not sourceRange Is Nothing Then

                    SourceRcount = sourceRange.Rows.Count

                    If rnum + SourceRcount >= BaseWks.Rows.Count Then
                        MsgBox "There are not enough rows in the target worksheet."
                        BaseWks.Columns.AutoFit
                        mybook.Close savechanges:=False
                        GoTo ExitTheSub
                    Else

                        ' Copy the file name in column A.
                        With sourceRange
                            BaseWks.Cells(rnum, "A"). _
                                    Resize(.Rows.Count).Value = MyFiles(FNum)
                        End With

                        ' Set the destination range.
                        Set destrange = BaseWks.Range("B" & rnum)

                        ' Copy the values from the source range
                        ' to the destination range.
                        With sourceRange
                            Set destrange = destrange. _
                                            Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count)
                        End With
                        destrange.Value = sourceRange.Value

                        rnum = rnum + SourceRcount
                    End If
                End If
                mybook.Close savechanges:=False
            End If

        Next FNum
        BaseWks.Columns.AutoFit
    End If

ExitTheSub:
    ' Restore the application properties.
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
        .Calculation = CalcMode
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you run that by me again, please? You want to look-up a column by name in an external sheet based on the column name of the result sheet and return that column name, if found, to the result sheet? If this is not correct please add some more notes.

Answer (score 1):

1.If you have permission to change file format then we can use `Range(defined_range_name)`
2.If you know the row/column that contains keywork, use Match("key",A1: A100, 1)
3.Otherwise, use Find:

```
Set retcell = Cells.Find(What:="keyword", After:=Cells(1,1), LookIn:=xlValues, _
        LookAt:= xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False , SearchFormat:=False)
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, but my files in the folder are more survey format, so I cannot copy whole column or whole row, I need formula to look for key words (which are questions in the survey) then return the cell below or adjacent cells - many thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

A common way to work with a cell relative to another cell is to use the Offset property. In the following example, the contents of the cell that's one row down and three columns over from the active cell on the active worksheet are formatted as double-underlined.

```
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 3).Font.Underline = xlDouble
```

Say the cell contain String=”Control Process” is A1, you can find A1 by

Set ControlProcessCell = Cells.Find(what:=”Control Process”………)

Then offset the cell to find the actual value

Set WantedCell = ControlProcessCell.Offset(1,0)

You may need to select the ControlProcessCell first which should be something like

ControlProcessCell.select